# Conditional if statements in wordpress to change the default header according to the page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have 3 headers.php  in a child theme for a premium theme. The issue is the first line of the code. I don't have a static front page and pretty permalinks is off due to localhost development, although when live it will use pretty permalinks.

My header.php file now looks like this:

```
<?php
    if (!is_page('')){
        include(STYLESHEETPATH.'/header-home.php');
    }
    elseif (is_page('gallery')){
        include(STYLESHEETPATH.'/header-gallery.php');
    } 
    else {
        include(STYLESHEETPATH.'/header-default.php');
    }
?>
```

The second line: if is not the page '' do header-home else give me a different header works!! However not like I would like. When I place the word home inside the '' then it does nothing as it does not find a static front page! Good I don't have one however all blogs have the header from if (!is_page('')). What word do I have to insert between the '' so that my change of header works for my homepage. I have tried p=0 page_id=0. Please Help

As you can see from my profile I'm a Newbie so I apologise in advance if I have really done something obviously stupid.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try either:

```
is_home();
```

or

```
is_front_page();
```

to get if you are in homepage or not.

More information [here for is_home](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home) and [here for is_front_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page).

Comment: Wow that was quick. Works perfectly. Where can I see the difference between is_home() and is_page(). I take it these are functions in wordpress? Many thanks I have a conditional header! Very Happy Many Thanks.

Comment: I am happy it worked! In the end of my answer I included links to the documentation of these two functions. There you can find more information about them and how they differ.